# Did Dooku know that the CIS was destined to fail and lose the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

This question actually comes from an EckhartsLadder video I watched some time back, can't remember which one, but it was about Star Wars and the Clone Wars.

As the question suggests, did Dooku know that the Confederacy of Independent Systems (CIS) was ultimately set up to fail and lose the Clone Wars? I mean, the Clone Wars were ultimately caused by Sidious to uproot and overthrow the Republic, as well as the Jedi, and instate a new order.

But did Dooku know this in the grand scheme of things, considering that he was the "face" of the CIS or was he kept in the dark about Sidious's master plan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dooku knew CIS was ultimately setup to fail, as he and Sidious had planned it all from the beginning:

The relevant dialog from the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) of *Attack of the Clones* is this:

> COUNT DOOKU emerges and walks to where the hooded figure of DARTH SIDIOUS stands  waiting. COUNT DOOKU bows.
>
> **COUNT DOOKU/DARTH TYRANUS**: The Force is with us, my Master.
>
> **DARTH SIDIOUS**: Welcome home, Lord Tyranus. You have done well.
>
> **COUNT DOOKU/DARTH TYRANUS**: I bring you good news, my Lord. The war has begun.
>
> **DARTH SIDIOUS**: Excellent. (smiling) Everything is going as planned.

Given that Dooku knew Sidious' true identity, he also definitely knew that Sidious wanted to rule the Galaxy and clearly that would only happen if CIS was ultimately defeated and the Republic transitioned to an Empire.

Comment: That only proves that Dooku knew that the war was part of the plan, not that *losing it* was part of the plan.

Comment: Given that Dooku knew Sidious' true identity, he definitely knew that Sidious wanted to rule the Galaxy and clearly that would only happen if CIS was ultimately defeated and the republic transitioned to an Empire. I'll add this in my response.

Comment: "Given that Dooku knew Sidious' true identity, he definitely knew that Sidious wanted to rule the Galaxy" is the only part that is not speculator. Perhaps Dooku thought the CIS winning was how the new rule would be established

Comment: @NKCampbell does have a valid point, I didn't really think about Dooku thinking the CIS winning would instate a new order.

Comment: Of course the minor detail of having hands and head cut off by Anakin might have been a bit of a surprise...

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar Your edit made the post harder to read as the name switched between different lines and was largely pointless so I have rolled it back.

Comment: Count Dooku = Darth Tyranus

Comment: @PeterM Link updated ;-)

Comment: Quote still doesn't prove anything.   The master controlling the Republic and the apprentice controlling the CIS seems like a good long term arrangement too.  Events always go according to plan until they catastrophically don't for Palpatine.